# IIS Redirection 301 of a link for only one domain without affecting the links of other domains

Tags: iis, redirect, rewritemap

i have two domains which share a similar link for a content that is /games-for-cats. What i want is redirecting the games-for-cats link to another link for FR website for instance but leaving the games-for-cats link untouched for other domain. I am using IIS and asp.net MVC so i tried doing this in the Web.Config but this isn't working. Below is what i tried to do.

```
 <rules>
          <rule name="Redirect rule pl for Redirects">  
            <match url=".*" />  
            <conditions>  
              <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(^(preprod\.test-website\.pl)(.*)$)" />  
            </conditions>  
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:3}" appendQueryString="false"  redirectType="Permanent" />  
          </rule>
    </rules>

<rewriteMaps>  
  <rewriteMap name="Redirects">  
    <add key="/games-for-cats" value="/link-to-be-redirected" />  

  </rewriteMap>  
</rewriteMaps>
```

Can someone guide to what the correct rewrite rule is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional condition to your rule which will trigger your rule for a specific domain only:

```
<rule name="Redirect rule pl for Redirects">  
    <match url=".*" />  
    <conditions>  
        <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />  
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^preprod\.test-website\.pl$" />  
    </conditions>  
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"  redirectType="Permanent" />  
</rule>
```